# Pictures and images for using in app designing

Tags: android

anyone knows a good website for getting pictures, images, characters,etc for an app I'm developing? I have tried looking for websites but couldnt find anything. maybe there isnt. but im pretty much a begginer and would love to know if there is one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try unsplash.com!

They have commercially-free images for any use. Moreover, use some of them for beautiful backgrounds of my app.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. im looking for more like graphic designed images. like characters bitmaps i can use . Like a swordman or a goblin, etc.

Comment: you creating a game or so?

Comment: then if you want characters like goblin and swordman - art pieces for game --- look for this --- http://opengameart.org/ ...upvote if this helps ;)